# Double Group-by then apply some functions?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have data that looks like this:

```
 country    source
0   UK       Ads
1   US       Seo
2   US       Seo
3   China    Seo
4   US       Seo
5   US       Seo
6   China    Seo
7   US       Ads
```

For each country I want to get the ratio of each source. I did a groupby on country and source and got the table below which has the total counts for each source in each country but not sure how to go from here.

```
df.groupby(['country', 'source']).size() 

country  source
China    Ads       21561
         Direct    17463
         Seo       37578
Germany  Ads        3760
         Direct     2864
         Seo        6432
UK       Ads       13518
         Direct    11131
         Seo       23801
US       Ads       49901
         Direct    40962
         Seo       87229
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
      Ads   SEO  Direct 

US    .3     .1   .4    
China .5     .3   .2
UK    .5     .3   .6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unstack` to transform the result from long to wide format and then calculate the ratio row by row using `apply` method:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = df.groupby(['country', 'source']).size().unstack(level=1,fill_value = 0).apply(lambda r: r/r.sum(), axis = 1)

df1
# source      Ads   Seo
#country        
#  China      0.0   1.0
#     UK      1.0   0.0
#     US      0.2   0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) to perform the frequency counts, followed by `apply` to normalize:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['country'], df['source']).apply(lambda r: r/r.sum(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Large sample set

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
n = 100000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(country=np.random.choice(('UK', 'US', 'China'), n),
         source=np.random.choice(('Ads', 'Seo', 'Direct'), n)))
```

#### Solution

```
size = df.groupby(['country', 'source']).size().unstack()
size.div(size.sum(1), axis=0)
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

**using data from this post**

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're diving along the wrong axis, as the columns add to 1, but the rows don't quite.  Hard to tell with the sample data as it's so evenly distributed, but try it with  something like `source=np.random.choice(('Ads', 'Seo', 'Direct'), n, p=(0.1, 0.1, 0.8)))` and compare the counts to the percentages.

Comment: @root you were absolutely correct.  Thx for that.  I fixed it.